# Screen Hangs and terminated

Tags: ios, swift, performance, uitableview

Screen gets hanged and terminated. I have trace down that because of my while loop ,screens hanged and app terminated.

While loop runs only of 10 times. when I reopen my application my Data is got saved.

How to null or deallocate the UITableViewcell

let itemcell:TableViewCell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: item) as! TableViewCell

Since   `self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "listdetails", for: item)` returning empty value .I have to use cellforRow.

Please provide input on this.

```
@IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let ndx = IndexPath(row:0, section: 0)
    var counter:Int = 0
    let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: ndx) as! TableViewCell
    let locationNameCell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row:1, section: 0)) as! TableViewCell
        let shoppingDetails = ShoppingDetails(context:managedContext)
        let storeName =  cell.storeName.text!
        let storeFlag  =  validateShoppingList(storeName: storeName)
        if storeFlag == true {
            let shoppingDetails = ShoppingDetails(context:managedContext)
            var listDetails :ListDetails!
            while counter < sectionRowCount {
                let item = IndexPath(row:counter, section: 1)
                 var itemcell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: item) as! TableViewCell

                let list = shoppingDetails.shoppingToList?.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableSet
                listDetails = ListDetails(context:managedContext)
                let listItem = itemcell.listItem.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
                listDetails.listItem = listItem
                var qty = itemcell.qtytextfield.text!
                if qty.isEmpty {
                    qty = "0"
                }
                var units =  itemcell.unitstextfield.text!
                if units.isEmpty {
                    units = ""
                }
                listDetails.qty = Int64(qty)!
                listDetails.units = itemcell.unitstextfield.text!
                listDetails.isChecked = false
                list.add(listDetails)
                shoppingDetails.addToShoppingToList(list)
                counter = counter + 1
                list.removeAllObjects()

            }
            shoppingDetails.storeName = storeName
            if locationNameCell.locationName.text != nil {
                shoppingDetails.location = locationNameCell.locationName.text!
            }
            shoppingDetails.initialLetter = (cell.storeName.text!).first?.description
            let seqNo:Int = ShoppingDetails.getSeqNo(managedObjectContext: managedContext) + 1
            shoppingDetails.seqNo =  Int32(seqNo)
            coreData.saveContext()
            let vc = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "StoreDisplayController") as! StoreDisplayController
            vc.managedContext = managedContext
            vc.coreData = coreData
            vc.storeName = cell.storeName.text!
          //  managedContext.delete(shoppingDetails)
         //   managedContext.delete(listDetails)
           // self.present(vc, animated:true, completion:nil)
          //  self.navigationController?.popToViewController(vc, animated: true)
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)    
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pExWo.jpg)

Comment: Add stacktrace if possible

Comment: What did you find out when you used the debugger?

Comment: One issue you are going to run into is if there are multiple empty listItems then you will be trying to present multiple alert controllers and that's not good.  Also even presenting those alerts the code will still go on and save the information without waiting for the alert controller.

Comment: @ScareCrow I did not get stackerror trace

Comment: @meaning-matters My debugger not working

Answer (score 0):

Save your data in this method as the user will scroll to fill all content

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   // ...

   //fill model array parameters from cell properties before data lost

            var itemcell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

            let list = shoppingDetails.shoppingToList?.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableSet
            listDetails = ListDetails(context:managedContext)
            let listItem = itemcell.listItem.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
            listDetails.listItem = listItem
            var qty = itemcell.qtytextfield.text!
            if qty.isEmpty {
                qty = "0"
            }
            var units =  itemcell.unitstextfield.text!
            if units.isEmpty {
                units = ""
            }
            listDetails.qty = Int64(qty)!
            listDetails.units = itemcell.unitstextfield.text!
            listDetails.isChecked = false
            list.add(listDetails)
            shoppingDetails.addToShoppingToList(list)


}
```

then when save button is clicked check that model array for empty item and scroll to that indexpath to fill

Comment: How to nil or deallocate the itemcell(TableViewCell)

Comment: I have to use self.tableView.cellForRow(at: item) as? TableViewCell when i   use self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "listdetails", for: item).I could not retrieve the value.please provide how to nullfiy the itemcell

Comment: I understand what you're trying to accomplish but keep in mind only visible cells of table will have values , also if you want to collect data you may try using scrollView instead as all items will be active at any scroll state , one final try to do with your code is to stretch the table height to equal to = allcells*cellheight so all cells can be rendered and run your for loop to see if any cell is nil , if there is even a one nil ,then try scrollview instead , also it's not reasonable to show alertController in for loop as many may be presented and lead to a crash

Comment: Thanks . I have removed the alertcontroller from the table . It is input form. I have to get data and save in database.Input form tableView with different cell. Each cell has a same identifier.

Comment: how to deallocate and empty the TableViewCell variable. Because we have to create  more than 20 tableviewcell.

Comment: see when you first see the tableview it really creates say 5 cells that fits in screen when you scroll it uses these 5 cells as the the new 5 cells with only changing content by cellforRow , so when user fills your data and scrolls this data is lost so your for loop can't access these data

Comment: Thanks.please see my image. func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   // ...

   //fill model array parameters from cell properties before data lost
} It is thowing an error.I cannot add the row

Comment: @ Sh_KhanThanks for me letting know the root cause of the problem.please help me how to solve this issue

Comment: see edit , note try to add indexpath of saved cell in didEnddisplayCell , so you can track empty cells and scroll to them when save is clicked